# Assign css class to another css class

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-3

Is it possible to reuse classes like that in css:

```
.aelement {display:block;....}
.aelementhover {color:#fff;....}
.remove a {
        //assign values from class .aelement here
}

.remove a:hover {
        //assign values from class .aelementhover here
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not with vanilla CSS but you can do that sort of thing with [less](http://lesscss.org/) or [sass](http://sass-lang.com/)